# How to delete DocumentDB database after portal update this week?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

It looks like the updates to the Azure Portal published today (17 October 2016) removed the Delete Database feature from the DocumentDB Overview blade. Did they move the feature or do I have to write code to do this? (I know how to do it in C# and I can figure out how to use PowerShell.)

Here's Microsoft's announcement about the [changes to the DocumentDB blade](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-portal-updates-improved-collections-management-and-new-metrics-page/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change was user experience only, we did not change anything about the resource hierarchy. We simply re-pivoted the experience around collections, as that is what you're working with most of the time.

We added the ability to delete databases back, see collections/browse/delete database.

In practice you rarely have a reason to use multiple databases and therefore delete databases. Database does not offer any functionality available to you via portal, and is not consuming any resources. If you are creating/deleting collections as part of your unit tests, you can just re-use the database, you don't have to delete it.

If you are using a database as an environment, please use documentdb account - that provides you with role based access,  so that you can define access policies for each environment

Comment: Cool, thanks. We want to periodically delete test databases that get cluttered with lots of bogus data during automated unit/integration testing. A test run might create 500 documents across 50 collections; easier to delete the whole database than to just let it grow geometrically.

Comment: thanks David, understood. A side note, using documentdb account as a container for your dev/test/staging environments is better than using databases, as you can leverage role-based access control and provide access to different environments to different people. But we will add delete / filter collections by database shortly.

Comment: quick update, we added "browse" collections blade that has database add/delete back, as well as filtering collections based on database...